# Pass by reference issue C++

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, overloading

Could someone help explain why when I multiply 2 numbers it returns 0, but 3 and 4 numbers it works?

I wrote this for a class but I just cant see whats wrong with it, Thanks.

Function is to multiply 2,3, or 4 numbers using overloaded functions and passing the product by reference.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void mult(int& product, int n1, int n2);
void mult(int& product, int n1, int n2, int n3);
void mult(int& product, int n1, int n2, int n3, int n4);

int main() {
    int product, n1, n2, n3, n4;
    char ans;

    do {
        product = 0;
        n1 = 0;
        n2 = 0;
        n3 = 0;
        n4 = 0;
        cout << "Enter 2-4 numbers to multiply\n";
        cout << "First number: ";
        cin >> n1;
        cout << "Second number: ";
        cin >> n2;
        cout << "Enter a 3rd number? (y/n):";
        cin >> ans;

        if (ans == 'y') {
            cout << "Third number: ";
            cin >> n3;
            cout << "Enter a 4th number? (y/n):";
            cin >> ans;
        } else {
            mult(product, n1, n2);
        }

        if (ans == 'y') {
            cout << "Fourth number: ";
            cin >> n4;
            mult(product, n1, n2, n3, n4);
        } else {
            mult(product, n1, n2, n3);
        }

        cout << "The product is " << product << endl << n1 << n2 << n3 << n4;
        cout << "Would you like to calculate another? (y/n):";
        cin >> ans;

    } while (ans == 'y');
}
```

Definitions

```
void mult(int& product, int n1, int n2)
{
    product = (n1 * n2);
    cout << product;
}
void mult(int& product, int n1, int n2, int n3)
{
    product = (n1 * n2 * n3);
}
void mult(int& product, int n1, int n2, int n3, int n4)
{
    product = (n1 * n2 * n3 * n4);
}
```

Comment: Different ways to approach this: one function with default parameters, pass a vector of numbers, etc. Also, you probably want to be consistent on when you do or do not `cout << product` in your `mult` functions.

Comment: Thank you for the help, the cout << product in the function was from debugging, I forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because your control structures executes the statement

```
else{mult(product,n1,n2,n3);}
```

Even when you only intended mult(product,n1,n2).  With only two numbers, n3 will be 0. So the result is zero as well.

You can solve it by restructuring it like this:

```
   cout << "Enter a 3rd number? (y/n):";
    cin >> ans;

    if (ans == 'y') {
        cout << "Third number: ";
        cin >> n3;
        cout << "Enter a 4th number? (y/n):";
        cin >> ans;
        if (ans == 'y') {
            cout << "Fourth number: ";
            cin >> n4;
            mult(product, n1, n2, n3, n4);
        } else {
            // Three numbers
            mult(product, n1, n2, n3);
        }
    } else {
        // Two numbers
        mult(product, n1, n2);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, super fast too

Answer (score 2):

Your conditionals are not set up correctly:

```
if (ans == 'y') 
{
        cout << "Third number: ";
        cin >> n3;
        cout << "Enter a 4th number? (y/n):";
        cin >> ans;
}
else
{
    mult(product, n1, n2); // product is set here correctly for 2 numbers
}

if (ans == 'y') // ans is STILL 'n' here
{
    cout << "Fourth number: ";
    cin >> n4;
    mult(product, n1, n2, n3, n4);  
}
else
{
    mult(product, n1, n2, n3); // this overwrites the correct product with 0 because n3 is 0
}
```

I'm assuming this is an academic exercise, so a more simple approach might look like:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int d = 0;
    int product = 0;

    unsigned short cnt = 0;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "Enter the number of operands (2-4):  ";
        if (!(std::cin >> cnt))
        {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cout << "Invalid number of operands!" << std::endl;
        }

    } while (cnt < 2 || cnt > 4); 

    std::cout << "Please enter your operands:  ";

    switch (cnt)
    {
    case 2:
        {
            std::cin >> a >> b; // error checking left out for simplicity
            mult(product, a, b);
            break;
        }
    case 3:
        {
            std::cin >> a >> b >> c;
            mult(product, a, b, c);
            break;
        }
    case 4:
        {
            std::cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;
            mult(product, a, b, c, d);
            break;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Product is " << product << std::endl;      

    return 0;
}
```